# libxml2 generator ( from xsd to C source code)

Tags: c, generator, libxml2

there is someone that know if exist a XSD code generator for C source code?
I have a lot of xsd files and I need to generate C struct and relative function fromXml and toXml.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ generation there is http://sourceforge.net/projects/xxsd2code/